# Java Stack vs Queue performance

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, stack, queue

So I have a list that can be in either a stack or queue. Is there any performance difference between the two?

Also I notice the java.utils implementation extends Vector. Would it be faster to make my own implementation, or maybe just directly use a Vector?

Comment: Without referring to a specific implementation the question is meaningless.

Comment: The most obvious answer I can give you is queue performs better in FIFO and stack performs better in FILO.

Comment: Just the default java.utils implementation I mentioned in the question. I can take from first or last.

Comment: You didn't mention any default implementation of the queue.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is probably simpler and faster than either.

Answer (score 8):

The java.util.Stack class is deprecated. Use a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead.

As far as performance, that depends on the implementation,

Comment: It is not deprecated. -1.

Comment: It is not deprecated, but it is not recommended to use it anymore as stated in the javadocs `A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.`.

Comment: I should have phrased that differently -- it is not officially deprecated, but like `Vector` its use is not recommended in modern Java programs.

Answer (score 4):

Stack and Vector are both synchronized. Use java.util.ArrayDeque as both Stack and Queue instead, see API:

> This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.

Comment: @nawfal But I have to add additional conditions i.e. when traversing a binary tree; since it prohibits null values?

Comment: @ColstonBod-oy I am not the author of this answer + not a java developer :)

Answer (score 1):

Performance depends on what data structure you going to use (arraylist, linkedlist etc) and what all operations you will be performing.

So depending on that you can decide your data structure. Will suggest you to go through Java API to know pluses and minuses of different API.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on usage patterns and the specific implementation.

In general:

- Use a **queue** if you want to process a stream of incoming items in the order that they are received (first-in-first-out or FIFO). Good for work lists and handling requests.
- Use a **stack** if you want to push and pop from the top of the stack only (last-in-first-out or LIFO). Good for recursive algorithms.

**P.S.** I wouldn't recommend using any of the old implementation that extend or utilise  `java.util.Vector`. There are many much better implementations available nowadays, depending on your exact use case.